apparmor is preventing plexmediaserver from deleting media files
KERNEL:6.8.0-38-generic
OS:Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
From syslog:
2024-07-14T13:48:21.285591+02:00 KEM-AS kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1720957701.283:508): apparmor="DENIED" operation="unlink" class="file" profile="snap.plexmediaserver.plexmediaserver" name=2F686F6D652F6B6D696C6C65722F446F776E6C6F6164732F546F7272656E74732F4C6962726172792F7765622F506F77657266756C4A5245202D204A6F655F526F67616E5F457870657269656E63655F323137345F2D5F416E6E69655F4A61636F6273656E2E6D7034 pid=1663 comm=504D532052657148616E646C6572 requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=0 ouid=1000
This is permitted by Plex but overridden by apparmor...
Anyone know how to modify the apparmor profile to allow this to function normally?
